# How can I select the rows having a longer text in one column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql like this, the text in mysql is stroed as "text" and the number is stored as "int"

```
+----+-----------------------------------+---------+
| date |                text             | number  |
+------+---------------------------------+---------+
| 12.1 | hello!                          | 10      |
| 12.1 | hello every one!                | 15      |
| 12.1 | hello every one! welcome here!  | 20      |
+------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

the longer the text and the bigger the number 
then how can I select the row having the longest text "hello every one! welcome here!"
now I have the code like this:
SELECT
date,max(text),max(number)
GROUP BY
date
but it didn't work
then what should I do?

Comment: you sure that you can store the date in this format?

Comment: is number = length(text)?

Comment: no,the number is not equal length(text)

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake of the table, the column date are the same @Satya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date, text, number from table order by length(text) desc, number LIMIT 1
```

Comment: and how can I echo the rows I select, I tried echo  $row['MAX(length(text))'] but it returned the number of the length of text,such as 100, I want to echo the text

Comment: Ah, you don't actually want the length of the text. I updated the answer, that should select the row with the longest text. Also, I just put `table` in the query since I didn't see what the name of your actual table was.

Comment: I already had a ORDER sentence in my SELECT, ORDER by id, how should I write the sentence of two ORDER

Comment: Right, it's the `limit 1` part that's going to give you what you want - notice the `order by` I put in there is ordering by *length of the text* descending, so the biggest one will be on top, then it limits by 1 which will only return the first row. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried in the case here it's OK, but my problem is more complicated, there are many other condition

Comment: If you explain the other conditions I might be able to help.

Comment: I just wonder if you have another solution for this problem just use MAX or GROUP BY or what?

Comment: here, I have a question, can I select the lattest insert row when rows have the same date.

Comment: Use a `datetime` type on the column that tracks the creation date so you'll have the time it was created as well as the date.